# More voltage make more current

Tags: voltage, current

Im electronic for beginner, I looked at different size of batteries, I am bit confused about volt and current in battery size,

AAA, A, C and D battery type has 1.5V and different currents,

I checked on internet and it said **"more volt make more current"**, but battery has 1.5v stay same and more current because of battery physical size are different?

If there are two AAA batteries together that mean 1.5v x2 = 3V that make more current, but Battery D is single and bigger has 1.5v and it has more current.

I see most DC Adaptor has 12V with different amp, for example:

12V 1A, 12V 6A

- Voltage stay same but more current that makes me confused, how does
  it work?

I'm confused with **"More Volt make more current"** and **"Same volt and
more current"?**

Comment: Check out Ohm’s law.

Comment: The key concept to understand is that you cannot directly control current, you can only control voltage. A circuit will draw only as much current as it "needs". When you see a power supply that is described as "12V 1A" it means that the supply will always provide 12V, and **up to** 1A. For example you could use this supply for a circuit that draws 250mA, 500mA or 1A. Using a 6A power supply does not mean that 6A will be supplied to the circuit, just that the supply is capable of supplying up to 6A if needed. If you have a circuit that draws 1A you could use a 1A supply, 6A supply or even 5000A

Comment: Cdvg, I'll just address the D cell vs AA or AAA. The D cell is like having lots of AA in parallel. Each AA can comply with up to some maximum current before you are using it well beyond its design. But two AA's in parallel can double that maximum. Three triples it. And a D cell has a lot more chemical mass to it so it can comply with a much larger maximum current and still be within its design limits. That's why they say "more current" in the D cell. Note that voltage doesn't even come into question. Others have talked about why that is so, so I'll avoid saying more.

Answer (score 1):

All batteries have internal resistance according to their voltage and Ah capacity or rated by CCA or ESR.

But for a fixed load R, I=V/R so it is proportional.

But if you see inside a 9V battery is made from 6 tiny 1.5V cells the ESR is small to begin with for each cell then 6 in series adds resistance =  6*ESR.

But if you compare even a AAA battery is larger than the internal 1.5V in a 9V battery, so for the same chemistry and quality (e.g. alkaline, Panasonic), You expect the higher short circuit current on the lower voltage but bigger cell AAA battery than the 9V battery.

To make it clear more current with voltage is only linear if the R is constant.  Te example above shows adding tiny cells in series to make 9V increases R so that assumption is false.

ESR = Voc /Isc
Equivalent series resistance equals the open cicuit voltage divided by the momentary short circuit current.